# How to fix PHP preg_replace() faulty result order?

Tags: php, include, preg-replace

The faulty result I get now is: `17th of July, 2011Today is .`

```
function finclude($file){
    include($file);
}
$str = "Today is {include 'date.php'}.";
echo preg_replace("/\{include '(.*)\'}/e", 'finclude("$1")', $str);
```

date.php :

```
<?php echo date('jS \of F'); ?>, 2011
```

**Expected result:** `Today is 17th of July.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function finclude($file){
    return include($file);
}

<?php return date('jS \of F'); ?>
```

Result isn't expected because You print `date`, then `finclude` return `null`, then you print `"Today is "+finclude`

Answer (score 1):

What you call faulty in your result order is actually caused by the execution order of your statements:

```
echo preg_replace("/\{include '(.*)\'}/e", 'finclude("$1")', $str);
```

Will start the output (`echo`) and then call the `preg_replace` function. In which you make use of the `e - eval` modifier to execute code, namely the function `finclude`.

So `finclude` get's executed *earlier* than `preg_replace` will return it's result.

So if `finclude` does output on its own, it will be displayed *in front of* the result of `preg_replace`.

Knowing this is half the solution to your problem. It's much likely you didn't intend this output order (your expected result differs) and you just wanted to make `finclude` return a value instead of outputting something. To convert output into a return value you can make use of an output buffer:

```
function finclude($file){
    ob_start();
    include($file);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
$str = "Today is {include 'date.php'}.";
echo preg_replace("/\{include '(.*)\'}/e", 'finclude("$1")', $str);
```

This will ensure that every output within `finclude` will be returned as a return value instead.

That done you can re-use existing code/includes that normally outputs within your search and replace operation. However using the `e` modifier always is dangerous and it normally should be prevented. So take care.

Comment: Someone who is mixing execution order and output order should first learn about that part to gain more health and security for the application in general. I hope my answer was insightful therefore. Preventing eval along the way might help. I think the securest way to get the same result would be that you request from yourself to create a variant of your code that works w/o eval as some sort of playful lesson.

Comment: Your snippet seems more correct and will return `Today is 17th of July., 2011`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to put `<?php return date('jS \of F'); ?>` in date.php